# In SQLite3, how can I do SQL-escaping in a LIKE clause?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to run a LIKE query in sqlite3 with the user's input safely escaped.  Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
char* query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(notes) LIKE '%?%'";
sqlite3_stmt* statement;
sqlite3_prepare_v2( database, query, -1, &statement, NULL );
```

But the ? is not honored when inside the LIKE expression.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char* query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(notes) LIKE '%' || ? || '%'";
```

But I recommend you look into using [FTS3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) for full text searching, because your queries will run *hundreds* of times faster than using brute-force `LIKE` queries.

Comment: +1: Oracle and PostgreSQL were the only other DBs I knew of that used double pipes for string concatenation (now ANSI standard too): http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: MySQL supports it too if you set SQL_MODE to `ANSI` or `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  The database is a tiny single-user DB, so performance should be adequate.